# issue with Grails mail plug in , Connection refused: connect

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I installed the mail plugin:

```
grails install-plugin mail
```

I added my config according to the plugin:

```
grails {
    mail {
      host = "smtp.gmail.com"
      port = 465
      username = "youraccount@gmail.com"
      password = "yourpassword"
      props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
}
```

I added a sendMail to my Bootstrap.groovy

```
class BootStrap {
    def mailService

    def init = { servletContext ->

        try{
            mailService.sendMail {
             from "username@gmail.com"
             to "username@gmail.com"
             subject "Hello"
             body "Mail"
            }
           }catch (Exception e){
            println e
           }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

but when i execute the application i get

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

the complete error log is

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: I left an answer which should have been left as a comment.  Apologies.  The content of that was to point out that the install-plugin command has been deprecated for some time now. You should instead edit BuildConfig.groovy and express the dependency there.

Comment: In my case, I was using a old password

Answer (score 1):

Restart the server and it'll work for you. It works for me when I do that.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I just pushed a sample project to [github.com/jeffbrown/maildemo](https://github.com/jeffbrown/maildemo) which includes your config exactly as posted, and it works.  See [Config.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/maildemo/blob/master/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy) and [BootStrap.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/maildemo/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy).

Are you behind a proxy which might be causing problems?